# How to point domain name to Amazon EC2 subdirectory

Tags: amazon-ec2, nameservers

I have a running ec2 server with apache I have to directory one is nwoow.com and other one is ommtimes.com under var/www/nwoow.com/public_html

I have also configure httpconf file  I follow this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

And I have configured it like this . nwoow I can access my site using ip/ommtimes.com and I have a host file configured as in example . How can I point my domain to this ip using nameserver help me to point my domain to the following directory nwoow.com and ommtimes.com.

Comment: Add  A records for both of your domains at your dns hosting (normally where you bought your domains) pointing to the ec2 ip address

Comment: I have added in my childnamserver nwoow.com and in Ip I added public ip of ec2 but it is not working

Comment: This would be better if you could show the actual configuration  in question. Linking out to this tutorial adds a layer of misdirection to provide a good answer.  You also need to make sure the ec2 server is part of a security group open public for web traffic (ports 80 and 443 if you need ssl).

Answer (score 0):

I created a site host using https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

and I just followed the tutorial and I was doing right and I just done one change see this host file I go to this file host file :

```
        127.0.0.1   localhost
        127.0.1.1   guest-desktop
        111.111.111.111 example.com
        111.111.111.111 test.com
```

Here I put my Public IP of AWS Then I go to godaddy account and I just change Manage DNS and I put the public IP inside my domain control panel I simply add Public IP and all the domains directly working when I put example.com